# syntax error in INSERT INTO” ms-access vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, syntax, insert

```
  Private Sub loadcombo_1_leader(name1 As String, name2 As String, name3 As Long)
        Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO [Combination Definitions] (ComboName, ComboType, AutoDesign, CaseType, CaseName, ScaleFactor, SteelDesign, ConcDesign, AlumDesign, ColdDesign, GUID, Notes) VALUES(@ComboName, @ComboType, @AutoDesign, @CaseType, @CaseName, @ScaleFactor, @SteelDesign, @ConcDesign, @AlumDesign, @ColdDesign, @GUID, @Notes)"
        COM = New OleDbCommand(sql, Con)
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComboName", name1)
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComboType", "Linear Add")
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AutoDesign", "No")
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CaseType", "Linear Static")
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CaseName", name2)
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScaleFactor", name3)
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SteelDesign", "None")
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConcDesign", "None")
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlumDesign", "None")
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColdDesign", "None")
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GUID", "")
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", "")
        Con.Open()
        COM.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: My suspicion was that one of your column names was a reserved word but there's no obvious candidates there. I don't think that `GUID` or `Notes` is but you might try wrapping them in brackets just in case.

Comment: I think jmcilhinney is spot-on with the reserved word idea: `GUID` appears in [List of reserved words in Access 2002 and in later versions of Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words).

Comment: I find it odd that a field named GUID would be left empty. Also, I don't allow empty strings in tables. If you aren't going to populate fields, why include them in the INSERT action?

Comment: your table name has a space. Did u check it? "Combination Definitions"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're doing enough pre-validation for the input arguments to your function to avoid the risk of a SQL injection, is it not more simple to just build and execute a fully formed INSERT statement like this?

```
Dim sql As String
Dim lngAffected As Long

sql = "INSERT INTO [Combination Definitions] (ComboName, ComboType, AutoDesign, CaseType, CaseName, ScaleFactor, SteelDesign, ConcDesign, AlumDesign, ColdDesign, GUID, Notes) "
sql = sql & "VALUES('" & name1 & "', 'Linear Add', 'No', 'Linear Static', '" & name2 & "', '" & name3 & "', 'None', 'None', 'None', '', '')"

COM.Execute lngAffected
```

You should in theory then also get a meaningful error back which will tell you what is wrong with the statement (if it's in the statement).

Another option is to take that generated SQL string and run it directly against your database to retrieve the same error message.

lngAffected also then gives you the added ability to validate the INSERT with a return value of 1 (row) once you deploy this to production.